# Macro records which page it is on - A possible solution?

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering

Although I use only LuaLaTeX, I believe this question is equally applicable to pdflatex (and maybe XeTeX). The question has been asked before, by several others in different ways.

Old Question: During compile, without having to re-compile, is it possible for a macro, situated in the main text, to know what page it is on?

Old Answer: No, due to the asynchronous page shipout routine. Although `\thepage` will print something, it may be wrong, because the page break was not already determined by the time that `thepage` was encountered. The best you can do is provide a `\label`, which will be recorded in the `aux` file, and interpreted by a second compile.

Now, in my case, I never use hyperlinks, because my document are for print-to-paper only. I load `hyperref` because it is needed for things involving PDF/X, but no links are ever created. And, although I would like a macro to know its page number, I do not actually have to print that number, and do not need to re-format anything based on the number. I merely wish to record the number, parse it, then write a message later to the log file, based on the number. Also, my layout is always double-sided, single column.

I believe it can be done! But I am not a good enough coder to know for sure.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % because the real document uses it for non-link reasons
\edef\myscramble{\pdfcreationdate}
% If using lualatex, either \usepackage{luatex85} or alternative synatax for date.
\begin{document}
\vspace*{6in} % so that the strange paragraph straddles pages
yada\par
yada\par
yada\par
yada\par
\noindent\hspace{\parindent}\label{alpha\myscramble}\thepage{} aaa aa aaaa aaa aaa aa a aa aa aaa aa a aa aa aaa aa aaa aa aaa  aaa aa aa  aaaaa aaa aaaaa a a aaaaaa aaaa aaaa aa aaaaa a aaaaa aaa a aaaa aa aaa aa aaa a aaaaa aaa a aa aaaa aa a aaaaa a aaaaa a aaaa a aaa aa aaaa aaaa aa aaaaa a aaaaa aaa a aaaa aa aaa aa aaa a aaaaa aaa a aa aaaa aa a aaaaa a aaaaa a aaaa a aaa aa \thepage\label{beta\myscramble}\par
yada\par
yada\par
\end{document}
```

Above, I used the current time as a way to prevent the labels from being read from `aux` on a subsequent compile. Each compile, the label names are different.

I discovered that the trick doesn't always work if the `\label` is the very first item in a paragraph. But it does work if I insert some space then remove it. In the above case, I removed then added back the `\parindent`.

As expected from asychronous layout, `\thepage` is 1 at both the beginning and end of the all-a paragraph, even though the print begins on page 1 and ends on page 2.

But if I look in the `aux` file, I see this:

```
\newlabel{alphaD:20180416194433-07'00'}{{}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
\newlabel{betaD:20180416194433-07'00'}{{}{2}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

That is, `aux` correctly knows that the paragraph begins on page 1, and ends on page 2. In my actual tests, I use a hash instead of the ordinary `\pdfcreationdate`, so there is no issue with punctuation.

This might not work for every circumstance (lists, etc.) but it seems to work for ordinary flowing text. If so, then it provides a way to determine (via macros) whether or not a specific paragraph, or other item, begins and ends on the same page. If that information is available before the log file closes, then it can be processed, providing a message such as "your paragraph straddles pages" as a potential warning.

NEW QUESTION 1: In the context of ordinary, flowing text, does the above make sense? That is, am I just lucky that it works in my tests, or should it generally work?

NEW QUESTION 2: How in the world can I grab the information that will be written to the `aux` file, and use it in a macro, before the current log file closes? I looked through some TeX code (re-written by `hyperref`) and my head spins.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, what you wrote is what I have in mind. So I muddled around, and made progress: Via `\LetLtxMacro` I can re-define `\@newl@bel` (it is in hyperref). So I can grab the arguments passed to that macro, store them in another macro of my own (expanded to plain text), then later parse the stored value using `\IfSubStr*` from package xstring. Needs the starred command due to tokens. Will investigate further, and report back.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed. Grabbing the `\pageref` and comparing (by parsing as strings, for example) is the hard part. Anyway: I have made progress, and can now do what I set out to do. Now I'm looking at how to focus on the widest possible use with clean code. Unless someone comes up with a better solution first, I'll post it here, tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "Should be" easy. But somewhere along the line, `\pageref` is re-defined as `\relax`, so that `\pageref{a}` is simply the string `\pageref{a}` and cannot be further expanded. Whether hyperref does that, or something else, is unclear. It could be a matter of when I call the macros, but I have tried different places. In any case, I have found a solution that does not directly involve `\pageref` but digs inside the code a bit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I posted a solution.

Comment: I cleaned up some of the comment thread

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I believe I have the solution. Instead of re-writing existing commands related to `\label` or `\pageref`, I looked at the code (in hyperref) and made my own. This generates a Warning if "span" text splits pages. Does not require second compile. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Tested with lualatex and pdflatex. Not tested with xetex, but presumed OK.
\usepackage{xifthen}
% My application requires hyperref, for reasons other than this question.
% Since hyperref rewrites some critical commands, I include it here.
% If you do not use hyperref, some of this may need to be modified:
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Will detect proper use of start and end span:
\newif \ifinsidespan
% Possibly not needed, but I like to initialize things:
\def\myspanstart#1{}
\def\myspanend#1{}
\def\myspanstartpage{}
\def\myspanendpage{}
% hyperref uses @mainaux instead of @auxout for this purpose:
\makeatletter
\def\startspan{\protected@write\@mainaux{\makebox[0pt][l]{~}}{%
  \string\myspanstart{\thepage}}%
}
\def\endspan{\protected@write\@mainaux{\makebox[0pt][l]{~}}{%
  \string\myspanend{\thepage}}%
}
\makeatother
% This prevents repeated compile runs from duplicating messages:
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\myspanstart#1{%
    \ifinsidespan%
      \ClassWarning{any}{Page #1. Cannot start span without prior end. ^^J}%
    \fi%
    \xdef\myspanstartpage{#1}%
    \global\insidespantrue%
  }
  \def\myspanend#1{%
    \ifinsidespan\else%
      \ClassWarning{any}{Page #1. Cannot end span without prior start. ^^J}%
    \fi%
    \global\insidespanfalse%
    \xdef\myspanendpage{#1}%
    % Now test whether start and end are on same page:
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\myspanstartpage}{\myspanendpage}}{}{%
      \ClassWarning{any}%
       {Span splits pages \myspanstartpage-\myspanendpage. ^^J}%
    }%
  }%
} % end \AtBeginDocument
\begin{document}
\vspace*{6in} % adjust to see effect
yada\par
yada\par
\startspan By changing the above vspace, you can move this paragraph up or down. If all of it fits on the same page, then you will not see a Warning message. However, if you adjust the above vspace so that this paragraph splits pages, then you will see the Warning message. Try 6.5in.\endspan\par
yada\par
yada\par
\clearpage
\vspace*{6.5in} % adjust to see effect
yada\par
yada\par
\startspan By changing the above vspace, you can move this paragraph up or down. If all of it fits on the same page, then you will not see a Warning message. However, if you adjust the above vspace so that this paragraph splits pages, then you will see the Warning message. Try 6.5in.\endspan\par
yada\par
yada\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes OK glad you got something working, you are missing some `%` and typesetting anything in the argument to `\protected@write` is odd, especially `\makebox[0pt][l]{~}` that argument is just intended to make local _definitions_ for the write. I guess that you want `{}` for that argument and use `\leavevmode\protected@write....` so the write happens inside the paragraph not before.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At leisure, I'll have another look. I did not know what the argument did, but by randomly typing got it to work. It seems to be the case that if the span start is the very first item in a paragraph, it is ineffective; it must be "provoked" by a prior item. The funky makebox with non-breaking space does the job. I don't know why. Anyway, if the code is used in an environment definition, some `\unskip` or `\ignorespaces` might also be needed.

Comment: the reason why it "works" can only be described as "accidental fall through" putting `\leavevmode` before the write will do what you want in a much safer way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'll have a word with the union steward about that. You did know that my method of "programming" involves a large staff of chimps randomly typing at recycled Windows Vista machines, didn't you? Once in a while, they find a solution by chance. But lately they have unionized and are demanding more bananas.

Comment: beware, I hear banana skins can be slippery